# php mysqli delete posted variable issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the php block below being used to try to delete a posted variable $super.  The "if" part of this statement runs and displays the variable that I am trying to remove *But it shows the echo as {variable} with braces around it, which is why I think maybe the sql isn't working*

```
<?php
    $sql="DELETE FROM `supervisors` WHERE supervisor_name='{$super}'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "$super";
        echo "1 record removed";
    }
    else{   
        die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Well, if `var_dump($super)` also has *{}* in it, then go back to the source of `$super` and check where it gets them.

Comment: btw, this `mysql_error()` you're mixing APIs here, which needs to read as `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: @DainisAbols You were right, the option value had some {} tossed in the string.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
$sql="DELETE FROM `supervisors` WHERE supervisor_name='{$super}'";
```

to

```
$sql="DELETE FROM `supervisors` WHERE supervisor_name='$super'";
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with it, adding *{}* inside "" means that the value between the braces is a variable